# My addSubview for an image adds a larger view than expected

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an image inside a table view cell where the user can user tap on the image the app adds a subview with that image in it. The table view can be longer than the screen. The issue is that if I have the table view scrolled up a bit and the user taps on the image, the image in the subview is scrolled up. My guess is that calling `newImageView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds` isn't what I need?

```
@IBAction func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imageView = sender.view as! UIImageView
    let bookImage = UIImageView(image: imageView.image)
    bookImage.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    bookImage.backgroundColor = .black
    bookImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    bookImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let bookImageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissFullscreenImage))
    bookImage.addGestureRecognizer(bookImageTap)
    self.view.addSubview(bookImage)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
}
```

this is what it’s suppose to look like wherever I tap it
[image: this is what it’s suppose to look like wherever I tap it]

this is what happens if I scroll the table view up and tap the image
[image: this is what happens if I scroll the table view up and tap the image]

Comment: Where do you want to add the image view? At the top left of the screen?

Comment: Oh, I see. What I'm trying to do is add the image to the view and have it centered when it appears.

Comment: You mean you want something like a zoom feature, so that when the user taps on an image, the image fills the whole screen? Can you show an image illustrating what you want to do?

Comment: I added the photos as requested

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: It solved the issue with scrolling but it still shows the background when I scroll up. I think with your help it will get me to where I need it to be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185583/discussion-between-sweeper-and-lamppost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.view` is a table view, which is a kind of scroll view. If you add a subview to that, it will scroll with the table view. I suppose you don't want that.

Therefore, you should not add the `bookImage` as a subview of `self.view`. You can instead add it as a subview of the `window`:

```
let window = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).window
window?.addSubview(bookImage)
```

Comment: As Sweeper also mentioned `If you want to show the status bar as well, make y UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height, and the height to be the screen height minus the status bar height.`